# How to use two regular expression variable values with match count -1 in ForEach controller

Tags: jmeter

How to use two regular expression variable values with match count -1 in ForEach controller.

JMeter version: 3.1

Scenario:
Questions List page>Each question has unique ID> Need to click each question on the list page and the HTTP request takes two parameters - QuestionID and Title

For this scenario I could achieve for one parameter (title) by using ForEach controller with regular expression match count set to -1.

When I have another RegExp for QuestionID with match count set to -1, how to use in the same ForEach controller since it takes only one input variable and puts that in one output variable. Below is the current test plan structure.

JMeter TestPlan structure:

The HTTP request looks like:
`POST https://test.com:xx/test`

POST BODY:

`mode=pr&questionId=454&Title=abcde`

Here I have to put/get questionId and Title variable values, each title will have unique questionId.

ThreadGroup

--Req1
--Req2

---RegEx (title): with Match No. -1 (Debug Sampler shows match count: 4)
`---RegEx (QuestionID): with MAtch No. -1 (Debug sampler shows match count: 2)

Loop Controller

---ForEach Controller (for title input variable)

----HTTP req using ForEach controller's output variable

Run the test> it is able to successfully iterate through title variable values however how to use QuestionID variable also in ForEach controller so that the HTTP request can have both RegExp variables.

Please guide.

Jmeter Version: 4.0
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Counter-QuesitonID-req:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inside you ForEach loop, in case for example if it's called `foreachController` using an internal index introduced in [JMeter 4.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

> ForEach Controller now expose their current iteration as a variable
>   named **jm**<"Name of your element">__idx

The problem it's started with 0, and QuestionID index start with 1,

So you need to increase value first by
1. Adding a Test action

2. Under it add User Parameters with variable name N and value which increment by 1:

   ```
   ${__intSum(${__jm__foreachController__idx},1,)}
   ```
3. then use `N` index to get correlate `QuestionID` variable inside loop using:

   ```
   ${__V(QuestionID_${N})}
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for guidance. However I am not able to make it to work. As suggested I have updated my 'ForEach Controller' name to 'foreachController' and correlated with QuestionID. I have attached screen shots. Please guide.

Comment: 1- are you using jmeter 4? 2 - didn't you removed the loop and kept only foreach controller? 3 - can you add a debug sampler under for each controller and show what variables you have?

Comment: Once again thanks. I have added relevant screen shots. Using Jmeter 4.0, I have only one foreach contoller, no loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding, it helped. Able to get two QuestionIDs and correlating.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element as a child of the ForEach Controller and configure it as follows:

   - Starting value: `1`
   - Increment: `1`
   - Maximum value: `${QuestionID_matchNr}`
   - Reference name: `counter`

     [image: JMeter Counter]
2. Refer generated value using [`__evalVar() function`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar) like:

   ```
   ${__evalVar(QuestionID_${counter})}
   ```

   where required

   [image: JMeter EvalVar]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. After following above steps, The QuestionID value is just replacing/correlating as just 'QuestionID_1', not with the actual question value. Attached screen shot.

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo, you should use `evalVar` function, not `eval`

Comment: Thanks for guiding. After updating to use evalVar able to get the value however it is not getting incremented (always taking the first QuestionID whereas QuestionID_match is 2 in Debug Sampler). The ForEach Controller has output variable for 'title' and it has two values and QuestionID also has two values hence was assuming it will be like QuestionID_1 value + title value 1; QuestionID_2 + title value 2. Please guide.